# Select Multi Option Blazor custom component javascript free

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

At this time, blazor doesn't support the binding for `<select multiple>` ..., it returns only the first selected option and not all of them.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5519

So i'm trying to make my own component to workaround this problem.
Here is what I have for now:

```
<select @bind="optionSelected">
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> option in Options) {
        <option value="@option.Key" style="@(Value.Contains(option.Key) ? "background-color: dodgerblue;" : "")">@option.Value</option>
    }
</select>

@code  {

    [Parameter] public List<string> Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<List<string>> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public Dictionary<string, string> Options { get; set; }

    private string _optionSelected;
    private string optionSelected {
        get { return _optionSelected; }
        set {
            if (optionSelected != null)
                OnOptionSelected(value);
            _optionSelected = "";
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        optionSelected = null;
    }

    private void OnOptionSelected(string value) {
        if (!Value.Contains(value))
            Value.Add(value);
        else
            Value.Remove(value);
        ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(Value);
    }

}
```

It works well but I'm wondering how I could upgrade this component, because actually I have to click the select again and again and I would like to click it once and then only use the shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on each option to add them into the `List<string> Value` without using Javascript